# which file is shown single product category page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a completely custom woocommerce website. for example, for a single product page, I used to single.php file and manage everything completely custom.
I need to know which file is shown on a single product category page in woocommerce to show products according to the current product category.

I tried the following files:

- taxonomy-product_cat.php
- taxonomy-product-cat.php
- taxonomy-product-category.php
- taxonomy-product_category.php
- archive.php
- category.php
- category-product_cat.php
- category-product-cat.php

Also, I tried the following files in woocommerce folder:

- archive-product.php
- taxonomy-product-cat.php

I really need to know single product category page is read from which file.

Comment: Woocommerce have its own templates. You need to add in your theme add_theme_support('woocommerce') to be able to use em. All templates are loaded from woocommerce/templates/ if you want to overwrite you can create your own folder Woocommerce and copy or write your own templates. The way you do it its not the best practice and in future when they update something you will find it hard to maintain. Also Woo is using own hooks that are optimized and protected and you dont need to worry about this part. Read more about it here - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: I copied all templates in my-theme/woocommerce folder, So, my question is which file is shown a single product category?
Which files should I overwrite?

Comment: If you look into the template for example taxonomy-product-cat.php you will see its loading wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' ); . If you look into content-product-cat.php file you will see there is loading hooks that call different stuff. Based on how you setup your products to show depends what its loading. Also dont copy all templates from woo if you wont modify them. Copy only what you need.